# Convert binary string to number

Tags: lisp, elisp

Pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find an answer. I have a string of 1s and 0s such as `"01001010"` - how would I parse that into a number?

Answer (score 7):

Use `string-to-number`, which optionally accepts the base:

```
(string-to-number "01001010" 2)
;; 74
```

Comment: Huh...my mistake, I thought I had tried that and it didn't take a radix parameter.

Comment: Please note that this function will `Return 0 if STRING cannot be parsed as an integer or floating point number`. Beware!

Answer (score 6):

As explained by @sds in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565902/convert-binary-string-to-number/57612097#comment101611344_57565944), `string-to-number` returns 0 if the conversion fails. This is unfortunate, since a return value of 0 could also means that the parsing succeeded. 
I'd rather use the Common Lisp version of this function, `cl-parse-integer`. The standard function is described in the [Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_parse_.htm), whereas the one in Emacs Lisp is slightly different (in particular, there is no secondary return value):

> **`(cl-parse-integer STRING &key START END RADIX JUNK-ALLOWED)`**
>
> Parse integer from the substring of *STRING* from *START* to *END*. *STRING*
>   may be surrounded by whitespace chars (chars with syntax `‘ ’`). Other
>   non-digit chars are considered junk. *RADIX* is an integer between 2 and
>   36, the default is 10.  Signal an error if the substring between *START*
>   and *END* cannot be parsed as an integer unless *JUNK-ALLOWED* is non-nil.

```
(cl-parse-integer "001010" :radix 2)
=> 10

(cl-parse-integer "0" :radix 2)
=> 0

;; exception on parse error
(cl-parse-integer "no" :radix 2)
=> Debugger: (error "Not an integer string: ‘no’")

;; no exception, but nil in case of errors
(cl-parse-integer "no" :radix 2 :junk-allowed t)
=> nil

;; no exception, parse as much as possible
(cl-parse-integer "010no" :radix 2 :junk-allowed t)
=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This thread has an elisp tag. Because it also has a lisp tag, I would like to show standard Common Lisp versions of two solutions. I checked these on LispWorks only. If my solutions are not standard Common Lisp, maybe someone will correct and improve my solutions.

For solutions

```
(string-to-number "01001010" 2)
```

and

```
(cl-parse-integer "001010" :radix 2)
```

LispWorks does not have **string-to-number** and does not have **cl-parse-integer**.
In LispWorks, you can use:

```
(parse-integer "01001010" :radix 2)
```

For the solution

```
(read (concat "#2r" STRING))
```

LispWorks does not have **concat**. You can use **concatenate** instead. **read** won't work on strings in LispWorks. You have to give **read** a stream.

In LispWorks, you can do this:

```
(read (make-string-input-stream (concatenate 'string "#2r" "01001010")))
```

You can also use **format** like this:

```
(read (make-string-input-stream (format nil "#2r~a" "01001010")))
```

Comment: You can abbreviate `(read (make-string-input-stream ...))` to `(read-from-string ...)`. And you can abbreviate `"#2r~a"` or `"#2r"` to `"#b~a"` or `"#b"`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems hacky by comparison, but FWIW you could also do this:

```
(read (concat "#2r" STRING))
```

i.e. `read` a single expression from STRING as a binary number.

This method *will* signal an error if the expression isn't valid.